# why API key (APPID) wont work in this code?

Tags: android, api

I try to make a weather app and I came to this problem with an API key and I don't know what to do!

```
public void findWeather(View view) {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    assert mgr != null;
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(cityName.getWindowToken(), 0);

    try {
        String encodedCityName = URLEncoder.encode(cityName.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+encodedCityName+"&APPID=94064dfafb01980f851258909ec27129");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not find weather", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use retrofit to handle REST Api web services call

Comment: check for billing..

Answer (score 0):

You can use either retrofit or volley to handle api calls
heres a link for refernece: https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

also check whether the api key can only be used for paid subscription accounts.some functions may not work with free accounts.